# Python dictionary hold array ranges?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am tryng to make a dict that could hold some array sniplets
like `[127:130, 122:124]` but `dict = {1:[127:130, 122:124], 2:[127:129, 122:123]}` doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this? It doesn't need to be dicts, but I want a bunch of these areas to be callable.

So I have 256x256 arrays and I want to select small areas in them for some calculations: 
`fft[127:130, 122:124]`

Would be great if the whole part between brackets could be in a dict

Comment: why not just save them as separate entries of a list.

Comment: Can I put that into the array then?

Comment: It doesn't let me do [[127:130, 122:124], [126:130, 122:125]]

Comment: Instead of trying to store it as `127:130`, you can store it as two entries in the list `127,130`, so then you will store four values in the lists inside...

Comment: I need 4 entries for one calculation, splitting them won't make it easier I think

Comment: Not splitting them, storing the four entries as a list is what i'm suggesting..

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) function. It returns a slice object that can be stored in a dictionary. eg:

```
slice_1 = slice(127, 130)
slice_2 = slice(122, 124)

slice_a = slice(127, 129)
slice_b = slice(122, 123)

d = {1:[slice_1, slice_2],
     2:[slice_a, slice_b]
     }

x = fft[d[1]]  # Same as fft[127:130, 122:124]
y = fft[d[2]]  # Same as fft[127:129, 122:123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing **numpy** arrays returns [a view, and not a copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing), maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(10)

b = a[3:6] # array([3, 4, 5])
a[4] = 0
#b is now array([ 3, 0,  5])

b[1] = 1

#a is now array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```